# Observing Value Error on Python code by reading data from excel

Tags: python, plotly

Below is my code and seeing value error for the same , Please suggest.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

def create_graphs(excel_path,html_path):

    df = pd.read_excel(excel_path)
    fig = px.line(df, x = "Date", y = "CPU_excluding_jmeter", title='Metrics')
    fig.show()

    with open(html_path, 'a') as f:
        f.write(fig.to_html(full_html=True))
        f.close()

    return
```

## Error Observed:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-1643babef93d> in <module>
     29     return
     30 
---> 31 create_graphs('/home/karthika.s1/Desktop/Discovery_system_profile-Thu-Mar-19-11-03-35-UTC-20201.xls',"/home/karthika.s1/Desktop/HTML/graph3.html",)

<ipython-input-93-1643babef93d> in create_graphs(excel_path, html_path)
      7 
      8     df = pd.read_excel(excel_path)
----> 9     fig = px.line(df, x = "Date", y = "Memory", title='Metrics')
     10     fig.show()
     11 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/express/_chart_types.py in line(data_frame, x, y, line_group, color, line_dash, hover_name, hover_data, custom_data, text, facet_row, facet_col, facet_col_wrap, error_x, error_x_minus, error_y, error_y_minus, animation_frame, animation_group, category_orders, labels, color_discrete_sequence, color_discrete_map, line_dash_sequence, line_dash_map, log_x, log_y, range_x, range_y, line_shape, render_mode, title, template, width, height)
    212     a polyline mark in 2D space.
    213     """
--> 214     return make_figure(args=locals(), constructor=go.Scatter)
    215 
    216 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/express/_core.py in make_figure(args, constructor, trace_patch, layout_patch)
   1363 
   1364     args, trace_specs, grouped_mappings, sizeref, show_colorbar = infer_config(
-> 1365         args, constructor, trace_patch
   1366     )
   1367     grouper = [x.grouper or one_group for x in grouped_mappings] or [one_group]

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/express/_core.py in infer_config(args, constructor, trace_patch)
   1208             all_attrables += [group_attr]
   1209 
-> 1210     args = build_dataframe(args, all_attrables, array_attrables)
   1211     if constructor in [go.Treemap, go.Sunburst] and args["path"] is not None:
   1212         args = process_dataframe_hierarchy(args)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/express/_core.py in build_dataframe(args, attrables, array_attrables)
    972                             "\n To use the index, pass it in directly as `df.index`."
    973                         )
--> 974                     raise ValueError(err_msg)
    975                 if length and len(df_input[argument]) != length:
    976                     raise ValueError(

ValueError: Value of 'y' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. 
Expected one of ['Date', ' Memory', 'CPU', ' Memory1', ' SVC-GO-CONTENT API CPU Load', ' SVC-GO-CONTENT API Memory', ' Migration API load in ', ' Migration API Memory in ', ' Events API Load in ', ' Events API Memory in ', ' Images API Load in ', ' Images API memory in ', ' Layouts API load in ', ' Layouts API memory in ', ' Recommandations API Load', ' Recommandations API memory', ' Sharks API Load', ' Sharks API memory', ' UpNext API Load', ' UpNext API memory', ' configurations API Load', ' configurations API Memory', ' Markers API load', ' Markers API memory', ' Users API Load', ' Users API Memory', ' Entitlement API Load', ' Entitlement API Memory', ' jenkins cpu', ' jenkins memory', ' CPU_excluding_jmeter'] but received: Memory
```

## Excel File

Facing this error when we use other columns apart from 'CPU' column

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU4kL.png)

Comment: I think there's more to the error. Can you post the previous lines as well? And how are you calling create_graphs?

Comment: @GarethMa Unable to attach the complete error is there a way we can attach the file.

Comment: try paste it in pastebin

Comment: ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/express/_core.py in infer_config(args, constructor, trace_patch)
   1208             all_attrables += [group_attr]
1210     args = build_dataframe(args, all_attrables, array_attrables)
   1211     if constructor in [go.Treemap, go.Sunburst] and args["path"] is not None:
   1212         args = process_dataframe_hierarchy(args)

Comment: it should say which line caused the error (from the main funnction)

Comment: @GarethMa pasted the complete error on the query "Error Observed " section.

Comment: Error shows problem with key Memory - so first check if you have this column in your DataFarme (before you use y="Memory"). You have

Comment: I checked your error and it shows you have column `' Memory'` with space at the beginning - so you have to use name with space `y=' Memory'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error shows you have columns

```
Expected one of ['Date', ' Memory', 'CPU', ' Memory1', ...
```

So column name has space at the beginning and you have to respect it

```
y=' Memory'
```

---

Or you have to remove spaces from names

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({' Memory': [], ' Memory1': []})
print('Before:', df.columns)

df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
print(' After:', df.columns)
```

Result

```
Before: Index([' Memory', ' Memory1'], dtype='object')
 After: Index(['Memory', 'Memory1'], dtype='object'
```